# PayPal IPN receives data, but postback is invalid

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Everything worked before the TLS 1.2 sandbox update.

But I've confirmed that my server is using TLS 1.2.
PayPal's [TLS test](https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#to-verify-your-php-and-tls-versions) is successful.
And my IPN script can correctly receive PayPal's handshake and data.

But when sending the postback data, it always gets invalid, with no other error message.
This is in the sandbox using the IPN simulator.

Using the exact same code as [PayPal's example IPN listener for PHP](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples).

I've tried all the IPN troubleshooting I could find, including:

1. Set purchase date to NULL
2. Set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
3. Set IPN data to UTF-8 in paypal's settings
4. Sending postback to https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
5. Sending data with cmd=_notify-validate and file_get_contents('php://input')

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contacted PayPal and they say their IPN Simulator is not working!

This is the last time I assume a major development tool by a huge corporation like PayPal would not be broken and unreported. Happens regularly with them.

"The IPN simulator is currently returning a "verify_sign=undefined" response. We have let our engineering team know, and they will get to work on fixing this tool.
 Your IPN script if fine, the test payments triggering an IPN confirm as much.
 So sorry about the confusion and the IPN Simulator not functioning correctly. I can keep your ticket open with me until I have an update on the simulator if you'd like, and I can let you know when it is fixed."

Comment: I've been pulling my hair out on this issue for a few hours. Like you, I didn't even consider that a testing tool could broken in such an incredulous way.

Unsurprisingly perhaps, I can confirm that the IPN callback works fine in production. Code can be tested by issuing a real transaction (for 0.01$ say). Note that an IPN notification can be resent in the "Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history" window.

Comment: Confirmed. After installing THREE libraries and having them all return invalid during IPN Simulator tests, I ran across this answer. I tried a $0.01 transaction with real money and it worked fine. THANK YOU for saving me many hours of frustration.

Comment: By the way, here is the best library I ran across. The other two I installed (including PayPal's official PHP code) did not work out of the box and took some tweaking. This one worked out of the box - https://github.com/overint/php-paypal-ipn

Comment: PayPal does say the sandbox payments work correctly. But not the IPN Simulator. Also, I emailed them again and they confirmed the IPN simulator is still broken.